# Identify Bad keys and remove from array

Tags: php

I am trying to identify a list of bad array bad keys from $xdata so that I can remove it from both $xdata and the matching key in $ydata

However I am getting the following errors in php: 
array_flip() expects parameter 1 to be array, integer given
array_diff_key(): Argument #2 is not an array in

Any idea what is causing this?

```
$badkeys = array();
//search array for empty x value
$badkeys = array_search('', $xdata);
//remove x and y values where empty x
$xdata = array_diff_key($xdata, array_flip($badkeys));
$ydata = array_diff_key($xdata, array_flip($badkeys));

//reset keys array
unset($badkeys);

//seach x array where data is less than 2 days ago (bugfix)
$keys = array_search(strtotime('-2 days'), strtotime($ydata));
//remove where ydata less than 2 days old (bugfix)
$xdata = array_diff_key($xdata, array_flip($keys));
$ydata = array_diff_key($ydata, array_flip($keys));
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `array_search` function returns the index of the first matched element, not the entire matches array. To get all matched keys, use `array_keys`:

```
// Search array for empty x value.
$badkeys = array_keys($xdata, '');
```

and

```
// Seach x array where data is less than 2 days ago (bugfix).
$keys = array_keys($xdata, strtotime("$ydata -2 days"));
```